# I fell into the void in creative pocket edition and lost everything. How can I get it back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was digging out an under ground room, when I went too far and fell I to the void. It was a really good world too. I had slept in a bed previously, and it let me re-spawn, but when I did my whole world was gone, there was only grass. What do I do? How can I get it back?

Comment: Your whole world was gone after respawning? How did you even manage to die in creative? Sorry but I don't really get it.

Comment: @Izzo you can still die in creative if you fall into the void. After a certain distance you start taking "[Void damage](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/The_Void?cookieSetup=true#Effects)".

Comment: @Ben Ah, I didn't know that, thanks. Then there's still the question of why it messed up his world..

Comment: Strangely enough on Bedrock Edition, you can't actually die in the void when in Creative, and only land on `Y = -40`.

Answer (score 2):

No sorry mate but unless you backed the world files you wont get it back.
The only time i have heard of this happening is on the PC edition on Hardcore mode but never seen it on Pocket Edition